# Replicating Cardex View of Roambi App

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, animation

I am interested in replicating the Cardex View that is seen in the [Roambi App](http://itunes.apple.com/app/roambi-visualizer/id315020789?mt=8).

By Cardex I mean

[image: This Image]

Please help.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I Have not tried this because I dont know how to go about it. It would be very kind if I could get some help.

Comment: My Bad.. I will rephrase my question.. Actually I would like to know how to implement this. Also Edited the Question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Nick Lockwood's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/422133/nick-lockwood) iCarousel, which can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel).

With iCarousel, you can create effects like this:

[image]

Comment: wow.. amazing.. Not exactly what I was searching for.. But this is nothing less.. and  hence accepting your answer.. Thank you. :) and hats off to Nick for an amazing work..

Comment: If you set the vertical property of the iCarousel, then you will get a better effect as it is in the cardex view

Answer (score 0):

well i repicated the same using cover flow, where i had to change the matrix co-ordinates. you might find the cover flow code in github

i think this link might help.

https://github.com/tuo/CoverFlow/tree/master/CoverFlow.xcodeproj